# Inequalities on kernels of compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, integral-operators

Suppose we have a $\sigma$-finite positive measure $\mu(v)$ on $\Bbb R^d$ and we have two positive kernels on $\Bbb R^d\times \Bbb R^d$ $k_1(v,u)>0$, $k_2(v,u)>0$. We define integral operators
$$K_i[f](v) =\int_{\Bbb R^d}k_i(v,u)f(u)d\mu(u).$$

We know by some external argument that $K_2:L^2(d\mu)\to L^2(d\mu)$ is a compact operator; furthermore, we know that there exist two strictly positive constants $C_+$ and $C_-$ such that $$C_-k_2\le k_1\le C_+k_2.$$

I want to deduce from these conditions that $K_1$ is a compact operator, but I can't see an evident path to prove it. It's possible to show that $K_1$ is bounded by examining negative and positive parts of $f$.

It's important to say that neither $k_1$ nor $k_2$ satisfies the Hilbert-Schmidt criterion (i.e. they are not $L^2(d\mu(v)d \mu(u))$). We can additionally suppose that $K_i$ are symmetric.

So, is there a way to prove that $K_1$ is compact (or to prove that it can be non-compact)?  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was found with the help of `shwedka` at [dxdy forum](http://dxdy.ru/topic80839.html). The result holds and there's an even more general formulation.

Suppose that we have two spaces with separable measures $(X,dm)$ and $(Y,dn)$; suppose also that $q\in[1,+\infty)$, $p\in (1,+\infty)$. The  operators $K_i$ are given by
$$K_i[f](y) = \int_{X}k_i(y,x)f(x)dm(x).$$
If
$$|k_1(x,y)|\le k_2(x,y)\quad (m,n)-a.e..$$
and $K_2:L^p(dm(x))\to L^q(dm(y))$ is compact, then $K_1:L^p(dm(x))\to L^q(dm(y))$ is compact, too. Note that we don't need positivity of $k_1$.

The proof, however, exceeds the format of math.SE. You can find it in the article by L.D. Pitt: `L. D. Pitt, A compactness condition for linear operators of function spaces. J. Operator Theory 1 1979, 49-54`.

You can also find a proof (in russian) in the book by Krasnoselskiy et al. "Integral operators in the spaces of integrable functions", ch.2, th. 5.6. (`Красносельский и др. "Интегральные операторы в пространствах суммируемых функций"`
гл. 2, п.5.6)

This result can be further generalised to banach lattices (P. G. Dodds and D. H. Fremlin, Compact operators in Banach lattices).