# An "academic" question on integral operators

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

This question is motivated by another one, asked by Cameron Williams: [Adjoint of an integral operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799373/adjoint-of-an-integral-operator/799431#799431)

Let us say that a Borel function $k:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ *defines an operator on $L^2$* if the following holds for every $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$:

(i) for almost every $y\in \mathbb R$, the function $x\mapsto k(x,y)f(x)$ is integrable on $\mathbb R$.

(ii) The function $T_kf$ (almost everywhere) defined by
$$T_kf(y)=\int_{\mathbb R} k(x,y)f(x)\, dx$$
belongs to $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Now here is the question: *Is it true that if $k$ defines an operator on $L^2$, then so does $\vert k\vert$?*

This question is purely "academic", i.e. it is very likely to have no "practical" interest. Usually, when one knows that a kernel $k$ defines an operator on $L^2$ in the above sense, this is because $k$ satisfies some condition (e.g. *Schur's test*) which is also satisfied by $\vert k\vert$. Still, I would like to know the answer just by curiosity. I have absolutely no intuition about it.

Comment: isn't this question was already asked there? It has an answer awarded with a bounty but I can't remember the exact link...

Comment: @Norbert I don't know. Please let me know I you find the link...

Comment: [here it is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652472/inequalities-on-kernels-of-compact-operators)

Comment: @Norbert Thanks. However, this doesn't seem to answer my question; but I should have a look at the reference given in the answer. Thanks again!